# How do silent letters emphasise the syllable in 'physics'?

Tags: pronunciation

> [[Source:]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter#English) Silent letters may help to put weight on a certain syllable, telling the reader to put more stress on the syllable (Compare physi**c**s to physi**que**s). [...]

In English, the IPA for 'physics' is [/ˈfɪzɪks/](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/physics),
and for 'physique' [/fɪˈziːk/](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/physique).
1. I see that **c** has fewer letters than **que**, but which are the silent letters?

2. How do the silent letters explain the difference in pronunciation?

PS: [This ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/227319/50720) motivated my reading about silent letters.

Comment: Often English words ending in a silent e have either primary or secondary stress on the last syllable. It's not a perfect rule. (examples: physique, giraffe, divine; compare to physics, riffraff, protein)

Comment: Saying "which letters are silent" is not possible because there is no way to prove which part of a spelling corresponds to which part of the pronunciation. However, most would consider the "e" in "physique" to be silent. The "u" might either be considered "silent," or part of a digraph "qu",
 depending on how one defines the term. The idea of "silent letters" is overly simplistic and cannot properly explain many elements of English spelling.

Comment: @OP isn't "physique" a borrowing from french? In French that would have ultimate syllable stress so English may have just carried that along.

Comment: @czypsu: yeah, it is. But, lots of words borrowed from French are not stressed on the last syllable, like "riffraff" and "protein" from my list above (although these words also have Germanic roots). Usually the words borrowed more recently will have word-final stress, but earlier borrowings may have initial stress. And the use of a "silent e" in the English spelling can also correlate with word-final stress, a good example of this contrast even in words of French origin is "moral" vs. "morale." It's not always a perfect correlation though; "garage" can be pronounced with both stress patterns.

Comment: I agree that ‘silent letters’ is not a useful concept here. Possibly this is better addressed in terms of larger units, like affixes: ‘-ics’ has the shorter vowel /ɪ/ and doesn’t get a stress, while ‘-ique’ has the longer vowel /i/ and does get stress. These differences may be due to historical circumstances, but those aren’t needed for this pretty reliable rule.

Comment: @Le: You've got to learn to read less silly texts. A statement like that is a giveaway that the author was clueless about language -- spelling has no effect on stress, and little enough on pronunciation. The real language is spoken; English writing is a modern invention, and the concept "silent letters" is simply stupid. All letters are silent; letters exist on a page, but sounds exist -- briefly -- in the ear, and can be represented any way at all; spelling is just medieval bureaucracy.

Comment: @jlawler: actually, there are a fair amount of correlations between spelling and pronunciation even in modern English. It's just that the "rules" linking them are complicated and have many exceptions, so they aren't usually considered very useful practically. Sometimes, however, even native speakers need to use them. If I write a novel with an imaginary species or something whose name is spelled "Banic" or "Banique," readers will generally formulate a pronunciation in their heads to go along with the spelling. Which pronunciation most readers will assume is affected by the spelling.

Comment: If everyone suddenly became blind and/or illiterate, words would still be pronounced the way they currently are (though that might not last long). I have a PhD in English grammar and linguistics, so I **like** English spelling. It's like an arid basin with fossils sticking up everywhere. I can recognize the fossils by the sediments they're encased in, and I know the natural histories of the individual species, so I can tell all kinds of things at a glance, like any professional. However, that's what it takes to make effective use of English spelling. Roughly, a Ph.D.

Comment: @jlawler: I guess it depends on what you mean by "effective." For people who while reading encounter a word they've never heard spoken, usually the most effective way of determining the pronunciation is to look it up in the dictionary. However, when learning to read, little children and non-native speakers do benefit from a knowledge of phonics -- the basic correspondences between spelling and sound. And any skilled English reader, Ph.D or no, should be able to interpret the pronunciation of "pseudo-words" fairly consistently. http://weallcanread.com/pseudowords-words-phonics.html

Comment: Right. One learns to recognize signs by constant attention and reading (and writing doesn't hurt, either). But try to explain the rules to somebody who hasn't been reading, or has been reading another language, and it all falls apart. Inevitably, people will overgeneralize the rules and then run up against applications of them in the wrong contexts. That's at least half of our questions here.

Comment: @jlawler True. I remember when I was beginning to learn English (I was ten or eleven), reading or writing it made no sense to me at all, even though, back then, I already considered myself an experianced (and keen) reader - of Czech. :-) And I also remember how I mispronounced **gesture** as [ˈgestʃə] based on my prior knowledge of words like _girl_, _give_ or _get_. The _-ture_ wouldn't help, although I got that part right based on _furniture_ and _future_. Now that I've learnt some "Romance" and German, spelling is a real treasury of words' histories, indeed! Perplexing, but amusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silent letters do not explain the difference in pronunciation. "Physic" and "physics" are mediaeval or renaissance borrowings from Latin physica. "Physique" is a recent (19th-century) borrowing from French retaining the French spelling and also the French pronunciation with a stressed final syllable.

Comment: True, they don't explain it. One might say they *suggest* it, though. For another similar pair of words, "moral" and "morale," the silent e on the latter is not a retention of the French spelling, but actually an innovation only present in the English spelling. It seems reasonable to suppose that the different stress compared to the already-existing English word "moral" influenced people to add an "e."